# Grafana query to filter on empty valued label

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is there a way to specify filtering on Grafana query to include only results which have a specific label empty?
*Or at least have the only results with the label specified, even if it has an empty value?*

My query looks like this. I want to list logs where I have `traceId` empty. Which unfortunately includes all logs where I do not have a `traceId` label.

```
{container="myproject-subfunction"}
|json|__error__ = ""
|traceId = ""
```

I want to distinguish between these two rows. And my current query includes both of them.

- Without the label `{"level":"info","message":"Some message 1"}`
- With the label empty `{"level":"info","message":"Some message 2","traceId":""}`

ps: This is about verifying a bugfix, where our code incorrectly logged empty fields.